# How to Downgrade MySQL from 8.0.33 to 8.0.28

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, excel, downgrade

I need to downgrade because I cannot use MySQL for Excel add-in. How can I do it? I use windows 8.

There is no information on the MySQL's website.

Comment: The add-in I mentioned only works on version 8.0.28 so I have to downgrade it.

Comment: I couldn't find a site where I can download version 8.0.28.

Comment: Hint: there's a dropdown on that page to select the version.

Comment: Do they explain why the add-in won't work with newer MySQLs?  Or did you try and it failed; if so, with what symptoms?

Comment: Please edit the question to add more information instead of using comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [Official MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html)

> Downgrade from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7, or from a MySQL 8.0 release to
> a previous MySQL 8.0 release, is not supported. The only supported
> alternative is to restore a backup taken before upgrading. It is
> therefore imperative that you back up your data before starting the
> upgrade process

Install a fresh MySQL 8.0.28 version which can be downloaded from [MySQL Product Archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/)

[image]

Backup existing database then restore it to the newly installed 8.0.28 version